# Tensorflow run on the correct GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I use the code below to run the model with GPU:0 but when I'm looking at the task manager it seems that there is no activity in the gpu0.

```
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    model,history,VALIDATION_ACCURACY,VALIDATION_F1,VALIDAITON_LOSS,callbacks_list=training_and_evaluation(epochs=120, verbose=1)
```

[Task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLraZ.png)

on nvidia-smi command it seems that the gpu0 is running:
[nvidia-smi command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u73GR.png)

I must say that I'm a little bit confused... in which GPU the model use?
and why the task manager and nvidia-smi present different performances?
Thank you!

Comment: Hello, writing the code itself is always apreciated instead of sharing the image of a code.

Comment: Could it be that the task manager and `nvidia-smi` use different IDs for the GPUs? Could you run the task manager parallelly with `nvidia-smi` and verify that?